# R ggplot: facet_grid with different geom_rects for each facet trouble

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a time series dataset of accelerometer data on which I've run some peak detections to identify different phases of the gait. I am using `ggplot` to plot the left and right leg data as two facets in a `facet_grid`, and now I want to overlay `geom_rect`s to show the different phases of gait for each leg. I can add the rect layers ok, but I cannot figure out how to keep the left `geom_rect`s to the left leg facet and the right `geom_rect`s to the right facet. For example, during the gait cycle when your weight is on the left leg (stance phase for the left), the right leg is swinging forward (swing phase for the right), so the phase timings are different. You can see this by visually comparing the time points of the left vs. right troughs.

[image: Gait Cycle Testing chart]

I've googled and SO'ed my way through the problem and I could not find an answer. The closest thing I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230376/geom-rect-on-some-panels-of-a-facet-wrap) but the author is using the same `geom_rect` among the facets so it is not quite what I want.  I attached a simplified Rscript and the data as `csv`'s. Can anybody give me some tips to make this plot?

[facet_rects_test.zip (.csv and R Script)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pJKTpI96bxOCBAEJ0Y4zkLbwEGImUReA/view?usp=sharing)

thanks!

Comment: If the data frame you're using to draw the rectangles has a `side` column marking which data goes in the `Left` facet and which in the `Right`, then that should be sufficient to get the data drawn in the correct facets.

Comment: I wasn't able to fully grok your plot code on a first pass, but one thing that stood out is constructions like `aes(xmin=acceldf$time_ms[swingStart], xmax=acceldf$time_ms[heelStrike]-1, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, fill="Swing")`. Normally you wouldn't name the data frame (especially a different data frame) or subset inside `aes`. You feed a data frame to `ggplot` or `geom_rect` using the `data` argument and just use bare variable names inside `aes`.

Comment: Trying to subset inside `aes` or making multiple calls to `geom_rect` seem like signs that your data ought to be melted into "longer" format or that you need an additional column to mark desired groupings so that you can call `geom_rect` once and use aesthetic mappings like `fill` to get different colored rectangles for different groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47408209/687112) using tidyr functions is a great solution. You can, of course, achieve the result you want with the reshape2 package you're already familiar with.

The critical element you were missing is that the faceting variable can be taken from multiple data arguments, as long as it has the same name and levels. The function below works with the data as you read it in (you probably want to put the function definition before its first use in your script, though!).

```
plotAccelerometerDataWithPhasesSuperimposed <- function(acceldf, phasesdf) {

  # melt the rows for column left/right in order to facet_wrap on it
  acceldf_melted <- melt(acceldf[, c('time_ms', 'Ly', 'Ry')],
                         id.vars = 'time_ms')

  # make the facet variables identical
  phasesdf$variable <- factor(phasesdf$side, levels = c('Left', 'Right'),
                              labels = c('Ly', 'Ry'))

  ggplot(acceldf_melted, aes(x=time_ms, y=value)) +

    # Phases
    geom_rect(data = phasesdf, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(
      xmin = acceldf$time_ms[swingStart],
      xmax = acceldf$time_ms[heelStrike] - 1,
      ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "Swing"), colour = NA, alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_rect(data = phasesdf, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(
      xmin = acceldf$time_ms[toeOff],
      xmax = acceldf$time_ms[swingEnd] - 1,
      ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "Pre-swing"), colour = NA, alpha = 0.3) +
    geom_rect(data = phasesdf, inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(
      xmin = acceldf$time_ms[heelStrike],
      xmax = acceldf$time_ms[toeOff] - 1,
      ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = "Stance"), colour = NA, alpha = 0.3) +

    # Lines
    facet_grid(variable~., labeller = labeller(
      variable = c(Ly = "Left", Ry = "Right"))) +
    labs(title = "Gait Phases by Accelerometer", x = "time (ms)",
         y = "Sensors Values") +
    geom_line() +
    scale_fill_manual('Phases',
      values = c('firebrick2', 'orange', 'steelblue2'),
      guide = guide_legend()) +
    guides(colour = FALSE) +
    theme(legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.position = "bottom",
          strip.text.y = element_text(size=16, colour = "blue"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is matter of getting the data into the right form.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

First, let's get `gait_cycle` converted to long format and named properly. Convert `Ly` and `Ry` to `Left` and `Right` and call the grouping variable `side` to match the `side` column in the `gaitPoints` data frame. Both data frames will then have the same `side` column that we'll use for facetting, ensuring that corresponding data from each data frame get plotted in the intended facet. The `gather` function converts the data frame to long format (it's in the `tidyr` package and is intended to supercede `melt` from `reshape2`).

```
gait_cycle_m = gait_cycle %>% 
  select(-X) %>% 
  rename(Left=Ly, Right=Ry) %>% 
  gather(side, value, -time_ms)
```

Now we need to get the the three gait `Phases` set up correctly for plotting. We want a "long" data frame so that we can make a single call to `geom_rect` and directly map data columns to aesthetics. Thus, we create `b` (beginning) and `e` (end) columns that will mark the beginning and end of each phase in the gait cycle. Then we create a `Phases` column that will become the `fill` aesthetic (that is, it will mark which phase of the gait each data row represents).

```
gaitPoints_new = data.frame(swingStart=gait_cycle$time_ms[gaitPoints$swingStart],
                            heelStrike=gait_cycle$time_ms[gaitPoints$heelStrike],
                            toeOff=gait_cycle$time_ms[gaitPoints$toeOff],
                            swingEnd=gait_cycle$time_ms[gaitPoints$swingEnd],
                            side=gaitPoints$side)

gaitPoints_new = bind_rows(gaitPoints_new %>% select(b=1,e=2,5) %>% mutate(Phases="Pre-swing"),
                           gaitPoints_new %>% select(b=2,e=3,5) %>% mutate(Phases="Stance"),
                           gaitPoints_new %>% select(b=3,e=4,5) %>% mutate(Phases="Swing"))
```

Once we've got the data set up properly, the plot is relatively straightforward. In the code below, we enter the `data` argument and `aes` mappings only inside the `geom` statements, so that there are no issues with `aes` inheritance.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data=gaitPoints_new, aes(xmin=b, xmax=e, ymin=-Inf, max=Inf, fill=Phases), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line(data=gait_cycle_m, aes(x=time_ms, y=value)) + 
  facet_grid(side ~ .) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('firebrick2','orange','steelblue2')) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x="Time (ms)", y="Sensor Values")
```

[image]