# How to use geom_rect to highlight specified facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a facet plot that I need to place a rectangle in or highlight 3 specific facets. Facets 5, 6, and 10. See Below:

[image]

I found some code referring to "geom_rect" that seems like it may work but it won't show up, also doesn't give me any error message. Here is the code:

```
weekly_TS_PDF<- ggplot(TS_stack, aes(x= TS_log, y = TS_depth, color= sentiment)) + 
 scale_y_reverse(limits= c(16,2), breaks= seq(16,2)) +
  geom_rect(data = data.frame(Week = 5), aes(xmin = -65, xmax = -55, ymin = 1, ymax = 16), alpha = .3, fill="grey", inherit.aes = F) +
  geom_point() + facet_grid(.~ Week) + geom_hline(data = week_avg_15E, aes(yintercept = x), linetype = "solid") +
  ylab("Target Depth (m)") + xlab("Mean Target Strength (dB)") + ggtitle("Mean TS by Depth by Week (12 hour resolution)") + 
  guides(color=guide_legend("Year"))
```

Reprex data:

```
X   TS_depth           Group.1         x        TS_log        Date_time      AMPM Week sentiment
1 1 9.593093 2020-12-01 18:00:00 5.390264e-07 -62.68390 2020-12-01 18:00:00   PM    5    Year 1
2 2 9.550032 2020-12-02 06:00:00 4.022841e-07 -63.95467 2020-12-02 06:00:00   AM    6    Year 1
3 3 9.677069 2020-12-02 18:00:00 6.277191e-07 -62.02235 2020-12-02 18:00:00   PM    7    Year 1
4 4 9.679256 2020-12-03 06:00:00 3.501608e-07 -64.55732 2020-12-03 06:00:00   AM    8    Year 1
5 5 9.606380 2020-12-03 18:00:00 6.698625e-07 -61.74014 2020-12-03 18:00:00   PM    9    Year 1
6 6 9.548408 2020-12-04 06:00:00 4.464622e-07 -63.50215 2020-12-04 06:00:00   AM   10    Year 1
```

I just need to highlight or put a rectangle in facets 5,6, and 10. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think an answer here has a solution to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230376/geom-rect-on-some-panels-of-a-facet-wrap

Comment: Further example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847559/conditionally-change-panel-background-with-facet-grid